# How to split a movie into many movie files, split by chapters?

Tags: macos, video

I'm trying to take a movie that I need to analyze for an essay and split it into 18 movie files, one for each chapter (as defined by pre-existing chapter markers), for ease of watching one scene at a time and then stopping to write about it. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I solved this by using [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr).

1. Select the movie as the source file.
2. Near the upper right of the Handbrake window, there's an option to select a range of chapters. Tell it to go from 1 to 1.
3. Name the destination file 1.mp4, so that it can be distinguished from the other files that are soon to be created.
4. Start the encoding.
5. Repeat this process for every chapter of the movie, clicking Add to Queue so that the files will be lined up to be created immediately after 1 is finished.

Sure enough, now I've got 18 movie files that together make up an entire film!

To my knowledge, no one has asked this question online before, so I figured I'd share my answer with the world. Hope it helps someone!

Comment: there really should be a one-click button to do all of these steps for you

Comment: in the preferences, select the chapter to be part of the output filename; then you can skip step 3.

Answer (score 4):

My solution is: In Handbrake> check **Create chapter markers**

Then load the movie into Lossless-cut ( [mifi](https://github.com/mifi) /
[**lossless-cut**](https://github.com/mifi/lossless-cut) / [releases](https://github.com/mifi/lossless-cut/releases/)).

It will (ask to) import the chapters as cut segments.

Very quick and easy!

Comment: The most practical answer ever.

Answer (score 0):

I recorded a tutorial on doing this with QuickTime which I believe is a little simpler than Handbrake. Let me know if this helps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g7MgVBGfFCo

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, without re-encoding. If you only want to split the video into multiple files you can use [mkvtoolnix](https://mkvtoolnix.download/) . Use handbrake to find the chapter timestamps and mkvtoolnix to do the splitting.

Answer (score 0):

## Movie Splitter

I wrote [Movie Splitter](https://miln.eu/moviesplitter/) to split movies by chapter. Both 3GPP and QuickTime chapter track information is supported:

> Movies can be **split using chapter information** embedded within the source movie. Chapter information is automatically detected by Movie Splitter.
>
> - Automatically by chapter marker
> - Into two halves
> - Into four quarters
> - Into unlimited custom sections
> - Into regular durations; 1 second to multi-hour sections

[image: Miln Movie Splitter screenshot]